# Implement trait as Proxy in scala3 by using macro?

Tags: scala, scala-3

Is it possible to implement trait as Proxy in scala3 by using macro?

For example, if I have a trait

```
trait PrintService:
    def printString(str: String): Unit
```

I would like to implement some kind of HTTP proxy by scala3 macro that would call a remote service.

I've tried with

```
val repr = TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol.declarations
```

but it returns only
List(method equals, method getClass, method $isInstanceOf$, method asInstanceOf, method $asInstanceOf$, method ##, method ==, method !=, method hashCode, method isInstanceOf, method toString)

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/11685